# Research on neural networks mimicking behavior

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, noise

My question is regarding neural networks mimicking noise specifically. The idea is to have a clean image and a neural network ( type does not matter ) mimicking noise. Like Perlin noise or noise on camera that comes from photo blitz or salt and pepper noise on a black and white image etc. What I would like to know if someone tried something like this and is there research published regarding something like that. The noise is specifically for images and 2D matrices.

Comment: Why do you want a neural network to generate random noise with specific distributions and for which there are well established techniques ? This sounds counterproductive.

Comment: The reasons are difficult to explain but the noise that i need is not reproducible with regular techniques.  For example noise behavior on a depth map from a Lidar while it is raining. The rain is tricky an creates all sorts of distorsion and effect. So my idea is to replicate the noise with a cnn or something else. As said it is an idea I have no clue if somebody tried this.

Comment: Funny. You mention classical noise types in your post but in fact want to depart form them.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a programming question, but I think you will have better answers in http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YvesDaoust OK. Now I understand your confusion. Well I have a situation with the images that are generated from the 3D scene that is artificial, so my images are clinically clean, and that creates a problem. I already tried to add  noise with non parametric model but it is dependent on data and bias.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thnx for the comment I will try it there.